# Controlling a 5V power supply with a 5V signal

Tags: power-supply, relay

The might sound like a dumb need. Why if I have a 5V control signal would I want to control a 5V load? The issue I am up against is a voltage drop over a long run. In a home automation setup the installer used an extended run from a 5V power supply that is switchable because it is plugged into a wattbox for power cycling in case the end powered device gets locked up. This is a great feature to have but the problem that the long run created is now having an unreliable voltage at the end point device. (In other words, it works most of the time but not all of the time)

Ideally, rather than trying to boost the supply voltage to compensate for the long run, I would like to have this long power supply run become a control signal run rather than power. Then, at the end point use that 5v signal (which is more like 4.2 under load) to control a local 5v 2A power supply. I guess I could easily control the AC power going to the adapter via a solid state relay but then I get into needing to mess around with the high voltage side of things. I thought it would be easier to put a relay on the low voltage side of the local power supply but the SSR I first tried had too much of a voltage drop across the output connection and I was back to square one.

Is there a low voltage relay type solution that would work for this? If so, please call out specifics because I am lost to find anything that makes sense.

Do NOT suggest running a lower gauge number wire. That is not possible in this setup and I need to use what is there. I also want to keep the power management where it is. I just want the power supply to be localized for stability.

If I am going down the wrong road here and the AC side is the best place to control on the local end let me know that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching a large current with a small one is usually done with a (MOSFET) transistor, especially for low voltage applications.

So this is what you might need:
(Notice that the MOSFET inverts the polarity of the switching signal in this circuit! 5V=LAMP ON, 0V=LAMP OFF)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5rDj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Doing some further digging it looks like what you are describing might just work. Going to see if I can implement tomorrow or the next day and report back here to confirm a working solution.

Comment: I ended up trying a P30N06LE which worked perfectly. Basically zero voltage drop across the MOSFET and a little more than 5v at the device I was looking to power locally. Bottom line this turned out to be an awesome solution. For my application I did put a little heat sink on the MOSFET but can't say I notice any heat output from it at all.